# PHP REST API XML Request return empty response when pass status export id it's working

Tags: php

this my code request and response api rest call

```
 $request='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <YourMembership>
        <Version>2.30</Version>
        <ApiKey>'.secretKey.'</ApiKey>
        <CallID>001</CallID>
        <SaPasscode>'.passCode.'</SaPasscode>
        <Call Method="Sa.Export.Status">
            <ExportID>'.$exportId.'</ExportID>
        </Call>
    </YourMembership>';

    $header = array(
    "Conten`enter code here`t-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset="utf-8"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($request),
    );
    $soap_do = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $response = curl_exec($soap_do);
```

when pass static value in exportid parameter it's working fine, in case i pass dynamic value (like mysql fetch data) not working.

Comment: Could it be that your `exportid` parameter fetched from DB has funny characters like `&` or `<`? Try to sanitize them like this: `<ExportID>'.htmlspecialchars($exportId).'</ExportID>`. Better yet, use XML manipulation library to create your XML request, but that would be a great step-up from your current code, of course.

Comment: Can you share 
1) example of data of $exportId
2) how you get the data from mysql fetch data ?

Comment: <ExportID>A849D44058E17CB300A70606D0E5200D52EC2102</ExportID> this is my export id format   2)  DB fetch export id like this,  $mysql="SELECT `export_id` FROM ac_export WHERE id=$id";
    $runMysql=mysqli_query($con,$mysql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
  $ExportID=mysqli_fetch_row($runMysql);
        $exportId=$ExportID[0];